# is it good to declare a function in views?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

i got situation where i have to work on legacy code. One thing, i have to do to have quick result is to define a function in views. Is it good ? how to avoid them ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advice when using MVC with php ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308021/advice-when-using-mvc-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's view logic: just create the function in the view. If used from multiple views: consider putting the function in a library.

If it's business logic: create the function in the appropriate place like a model.

Comment: I disagree - you should not create functions within views. Ho hum.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a view template file, which is used to generate a user interface element, I would personally say that is not ideal to define functions within it. Imagine the things that you may with to do with this view in the future:

- split it up into smaller UI elements
- include it within other UI elements
- unit-test it
- render it multiple times in one request
- reuse those functions within other views

All of these will be problematic if there are functions defined (PHP does not allow you to re-define functions). It's much better to [separate concens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) as much as possible. For example, you can put your view-related functions in a [view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html) and associate it with the view in the controller.

All the best!